# Mongo DB Query Analytics not showing in PMM tool

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, percona, atlas, pmm-server

I have a docker service and created PMM Server and Postgresql and Mongo DB on that docker and I have enabled the pmm client for getting metrics to the PMM interface metrics are came. But I am unable to query analytics for Mongo DB, it shows empty.

I have installed an agent and do query profiling on that Mongo DB but still I am unable to get the query analytics for Mongo DB, How can I solve this error?

Comment: If i select time range last 48 hours it shows only one query, But recent queries are not available in PMM query analytics.